# java update crashed application, workaround throws error

Tags: java, osx-snow-leopard

I'm working on a Mac OS X (10.6.8) and there was a very recent Java Update to 1.6.0_29. Now one of my application frequently stops working (never ending spinning wheel). The people who developed this software told me that they cannot solve this problem (seems to be more on the Java side and seems to be hardly reproducible) and offered a workaround. I took the old JDK (backup) and copied it to the application folder and then I had to start the application with a shell script.
But now I get this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libjli.jnilib
  Referenced from: /Applications/app_xyz/jre/bin/java
  Reason: image not found
./start_app_xyz.sh: line 43:  1870 Trace/BPT trap          "$JAVA" $VMARGS -classpath $CLASSPATH org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main $APPARGS
/Applications/app_xyz
```

I have no idea if this problem can be solved somehow. If anybody knows a solution, let me know!

Update on my problem:

Now, I've replaced the old JDK by one from another machine and I get an new error message:

```
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: for
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: for
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
/Applications/app_xyz
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Sounds like an SWT application with an old `JavaApplicationStub` and/or incompatible JNI libs.

Comment: is there anything I can do to get it running? (I'm not the developer, so I cannot change anything at the application itself...)

Comment: I'd defer to the developers, but updating the stub or the [libraries](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/) may help.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this same message from a failed Java Update in Mountain Lion on my desktop. The solution was to copy the Java runtime jdk implementation from my laptop.  However, I got it wrong the first time and mucked up the symbolic links and the permissions for all of the files.

The `libjli.jnilib` file (in `Libraries/` in my case) ought to include executable.

Check that you correctly copied the files in your old JDK and preserved all system/user permissions.

My solution was to tar the files on my laptop and untar them in-situ on my desktop, preserving links and permissions. I did this under sudo so as to preserve `root:wheel` ownership.

Good luck.